# How to convert an image to base64 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm trying to write a file upload script for use in a secure corporate intranet and having just a little trouble...

In the following code, I get no errors and all my debugging looks like everything is working, but the end result is always a 'blank' image:

```
var ctx = document.createElement('canvas');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
img.src = $('#UpdateImage:file');

var imgStr = ctx.toDataURL("image/png", "");
document.getElementById("Item_Create_Image_Avatar").src = imgStr;
```

When I "inspect element" on the 'Item_Create_Image_Avatar' object, the 'src' value looks absolutely perfect:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" id="Item_Create_Image_Avatar" style="vertical-align:top">
```

Why is my image coming in as blank?

Comment: I think the problem is with setting the 'src' of the 'img' to a file:  img.src = $('#UpdateImage:file');  Then converting that to a 'dataURL' is giving me a base64 string that always shows as blank because it's not using the actual image info...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Comment: Regarding @HaNdTriX link look at his function he wrote, which seems to work great. **[Image to Base64](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/YvQ5y/)**

Answer (score 4):

Found This.

```
Select a File to Load:
<input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" onchange="loadImageFileAsURL();" />

<div id="imgTest"></div>


<script type='text/javascript'>

function loadImageFileAsURL(){

    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
    if (filesSelected.length > 0){
        var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
            var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

            var divTest = document.getElementById("imgTest");
            var newImage = document.createElement('img');
            newImage.src = srcData;

            divTest.innerHTML = newImage.outerHTML;

        }

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }
}

</script>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Source: [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript/23669825#23669825)

Comment: Edited a line of your code, since it was having issue with var declaration for document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML.. Its now working like a charm... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Data URL of the image after it loaded, you should get the Data URL after it loaded

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
   imgStr = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", "");
   document.getElementById("Item_Create_Image_Avatar").src = imgStr;
}
img.src = $('#UpdateImage:file');
```

EDIT: Included the rest of the code
EDIT2: Edited stupid error regarding canvas and its context

Comment: This doesn't work... Now instead of a blank image, I get nothing at all.  The image doesn't change in the slightest bit and inspecting the element reveals the 'src' is not getting updated.

Comment: I hope you just replace the .onload part of your original code? The rest of your code should remain unchanged. Answer edited accordingly ...

Comment: document.createElement('canvas') will return canvas, not context