# How to decode my json string that should be a image url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, encryption

I have a json file that contains images url, I guess that's an url, it looks like this: `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`

So based on this, how to understand this and get the image it represents? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a PNG file encoded in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). You can use a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) to display it in a HTML `<img>` tag:

```js
const imageBase64 = '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';
const imageUrl = 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageBase64;
document.querySelector('img').src = imageUrl;
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<img>
```

The image is white and has transparent background, so I changed the page background to black to make the image visible.

---

If you want to just decode the string, you can use the [`atob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob) function:

```js
const imageBase64 = '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';
document.body.textContent = atob(imageBase64);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a Base64 encoded image. You can display it in HTML like this:

```css
body {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64, 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" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an `Base64` image source, if you try to do this in an html page

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">`

You will get an image an embedded on html

I've tried on the chrome and get an image 54x51 transparent with a symbol on it.

Also if you try to decode this with Base64 and save in a file with it respect extension, you will get your image file. I've done in ruby like this and i could get the file.

`` File.open(`pwd`.chomp+"/image.png", "w+") do|f| 
 f.write(Base64.decode64("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"))
end ``

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an URL; it is the base64 representation of a PNG image.
You could display it like this, assuming you have jQuery and an image with ID myimg in your document:

```
$("#myimg").attr("src","data:image/png;base64,"+yourData);
```

Comment: How did you tell it's an png?

Comment: I just used one of the many base64 decoder online; I saw the header of the file is PNG

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a base64 encoded image. You have standard functions to decode it. Check out some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227078/convert-base64-to-image-in-javascript-jquery).