# how to display an base64 string into an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, base64

I am trying to display an base 64 string into image in html page ...
It showing  some error...[error look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ciBp.png)
here is my code 
    
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var username="srk";
        var url = "http://localhost/login/image/displayimage.php?username="+username+"";
        $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
            console.log(result);

```
        $.each(result, function(i, field) {
            var id = field.id;
            var photo = field.photo; //base 64 string is stored in photo


        $("#listview").append("<img src='"+photo+"' alt='loading'>");
});
    });
});

    </script>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
    <ul id="listview"  ></ul>
```

base 64 string look like 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEUAAABlCAYAAAAbIS4fAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAKT2lDQ1BQaG90b3Nob3AgSUNDIHByb2ZpbGUAAHjanVNnVFPpFj333vRCS4iAlEtvUhUIIFJCi4AUkSYqIQkQSoghodkVUcERRUUEG8igiAOOjoCMFVEsDIoK2AfkIaKOg6OIisr74Xuja9a89 bN/rXXPues852zzwfACAyWSDNRNYAMqUIeEeCDx8TG4eQuQIEKJHAAEAizZCFz/SMBAPh PDwrIsAHvgABeNMLCADATZvAMByH/w/qQplcAYCEAcB0kThLCIAUAEB6jkKmAEBGAYCdmCZTAKAEAGDLY2LjAFAtAGAnf bTAICd Jl7AQBblCEVAaCRACATZYhEAGg7AKzPVopFAFgwABRmS8Q5ANgtADBJV2ZIALC3AMDOEAuyAAgMADBRiIUpAAR7AGDIIyN4AISZABRG8lc88SuuEOcqAAB4mbI8uSQ5RYFbCC1xB1dXLh4ozkkXKxQ2YQJhmkAuwnmZGTKBNA/g88wAAKCRFRHgg/P9eM4Ors7ONo62Dl8t6r8G/yJiYuP 5c rcEAAAOF0ftH LC zGoA7BoBt/qIl7gRoXgugdfeLZrIPQLUAoOnaV/Nw H48PEWhkLnZ2eXk5NhKxEJbYcpXff5nwl/AV/1s X48/Pf14L7iJIEyXYFHBPjgwsz0TKUcz5IJhGLc5o9H/LcL//wd0yLESWK5WCoU41EScY5EmozzMqUiiUKSKcUl0v9k4t8s wM 3zUAsGo AXuRLahdYwP2SycQWHTA4vcAAPK7b8HUKAgDgGiD4c93/ 8//UegJQCAZkmScQAAXkQkLlTKsz/HCAAARKCBKrBBG/TBGCzABhzBBdzBC/xgNoRCJMTCQhBCCmSAHHJgKayCQiiGzbAdKmAv1EAdNMBRaIaTcA4uwlW4Dj1wD/phCJ7BKLyBCQRByAgTYSHaiAFiilgjjggXmYX4IcFIBBKLJCDJiBRRIkuRNUgxUopUIFVIHfI9cgI5h1xGupE7yAAygvyGvEcxlIGyUT3UDLVDuag3GoRGogvQZHQxmo8WoJvQcrQaPYw2oefQq2gP2o8 Q8cwwOgYBzPEbDAuxsNCsTgsCZNjy7EirAyrxhqwVqwDu4n1Y8 xdwQSgUXACTYEd0IgYR5BSFhMWE7YSKggHCQ0EdoJNwkDhFHCJyKTqEu0JroR cQYYjIxh1hILCPWEo8TLxB7iEPENyQSiUMyJ7mQAkmxpFTSEtJG0m5SI ksqZs0SBojk8naZGuyBzmULCAryIXkneTD5DPkG Qh8lsKnWJAcaT4U IoUspqShnlEOU05QZlmDJBVaOaUt2ooVQRNY9aQq2htlKvUYeoEzR1mjnNgxZJS6WtopXTGmgXaPdpr h0uhHdlR5Ol9BX0svpR iX6AP0dwwNhhWDx4hnKBmbGAcYZxl3GK YTKYZ04sZx1QwNzHrmOeZD5lvVVgqtip8FZHKCpVKlSaVGyovVKmqpqreqgtV81XLVI pXlN9rkZVM1PjqQnUlqtVqp1Q61MbU2epO6iHqmeob1Q/pH5Z/YkGWcNMw09DpFGgsV/jvMYgC2MZs3gsIWsNq4Z1gTXEJrHN2Xx2KruY/R27iz2qqaE5QzNKM1ezUvOUZj8H45hx Jx0TgnnKKeX836K3hTvKeIpG6Y0TLkxZVxrqpaXllirSKtRq0frvTau7aedpr1Fu1n7gQ5Bx0onXCdHZ4/OBZ3nU9lT3acKpxZNPTr1ri6qa6UbobtEd79up 6Ynr5egJ5Mb6feeb3n hx9L/1U/W36p/VHDFgGswwkBtsMzhg8xTVxbzwdL8fb8VFDXcNAQ6VhlWGX4YSRudE8o9VGjUYPjGnGXOMk423GbcajJgYmISZLTepN7ppSTbmmKaY7TDtMx83MzaLN1pk1mz0x1zLnm eb15vft2BaeFostqi2uGVJsuRaplnutrxuhVo5WaVYVVpds0atna0l1rutu6cRp7lOk06rntZnw7Dxtsm2qbcZsOXYBtuutm22fWFnYhdnt8Wuw 6TvZN9un2N/T0HDYfZDqsdWh1 c7RyFDpWOt6azpzuP33F9JbpL2dYzxDP2DPjthPLKcRpnVOb00dnF2e5c4PziIuJS4LLLpc Lpsbxt3IveRKdPVxXeF60vWdm7Obwu2o26/uNu5p7ofcn8w0nymeWTNz0MPIQ BR5dE/C5 VMGvfrH5PQ0 BZ7XnIy9jL5FXrdewt6V3qvdh7xc 9j5yn M 4zw33jLeWV/MN8C3yLfLT8Nvnl F30N/I/9k/3r/0QCngCUBZwOJgUGBWwL7 Hp8Ib OPzrbZfay2e1BjKC5QRVBj4KtguXBrSFoyOyQrSH355jOkc5pDoVQfujW0Adh5mGLw34MJ4WHhVeGP45wiFga0TGXNXfR3ENz30T6RJZE3ptnMU85ry1KNSo qi5qPNo3ujS6P8YuZlnM1VidWElsSxw5LiquNm5svt/87fOH4p3iC N7F5gvyF1weaHOwvSFpxapLhIsOpZATIhOOJTwQRAqqBaMJfITdyWOCnnCHcJnIi/RNtGI2ENcKh5O8kgqTXqS7JG8NXkkxTOlLOW5hCepkLxMDUzdmzqeFpp2IG0yPTq9MYOSkZBxQqohTZO2Z pn5mZ2y6xlhbL xW6Lty8elQfJa7OQrAVZLQq2QqboVFoo1yoHsmdlV2a/zYnKOZarnivN7cyzytuQN5zvn//tEsIS4ZK2pYZLVy0dWOa9rGo5sjxxedsK4xUFK4ZWBqw8uIq2Km3VT6vtV5eufr0mek1rgV7ByoLBtQFr6wtVCuWFfevc1 1dT1gvWd 1YfqGnRs FYmKrhTbF5cVf9go3HjlG4dvyr Z3JS0qavEuWTPZtJm6ebeLZ5bDpaql aXDm4N2dq0Dd9WtO319kXbL5fNKNu7g7ZDuaO/PLi8ZafJzs07P1SkVPRU lQ27tLdtWHX G7R7ht7vPY07NXbW7z3/T7JvttVAVVN1WbVZftJ 7P3P66Jqun4lvttXa1ObXHtxwPSA/0HIw6217nU1R3SPVRSj9Yr60cOxx  /p3vdy0NNg1VjZzG4iNwRHnk6fcJ3/ceDTradox7rOEH0x92HWcdL2pCmvKaRptTmvtbYlu6T8w 0dbq3nr8R9sfD5w0PFl5SvNUyWna6YLTk2fyz4ydlZ19fi753GDborZ752PO32oPb  6EHTh0kX/i c7vDvOXPK4dPKy2 UTV7hXmq86X23qdOo8/pPTT8e7nLuarrlca7nuer21e2b36RueN87d9L158Rb/1tWeOT3dvfN6b/fF9/XfFt1 cif9zsu72Xcn7q28T7xf9EDtQdlD3YfVP1v 3Njv3H9qwHeg89HcR/cGhYPP/pH1jw9DBY Zj8uGDYbrnjg OTniP3L96fynQ89kzyaeF/6i/suuFxYvfvjV69fO0ZjRoZfyl5O/bXyl/erA6xmv28bCxh6 yXgzMV70VvvtwXfcdx3vo98PT R8IH8o/2j5sfVT0Kf7kxmTk/8EA5jz/GMzLdsAAAAgY0hSTQAAeiUAAICDAAD5/wAAgOkAAHUwAADqYAAAOpgAABdvkl/FRgAAQq5JREFUeNrUnHeYnVXV9n/Pfsrp50zvJb333hOSAIFAJKEqCiqCgoCioIiKCiJKl2IBkSpIl15CSUghIT2kZ5KZSaaXc2ZOf9p vj9iQ1GE9/38rm9d1/wz1zV79r6ftde 173X2ornefy9bdu505g0fkJ06tQZ/lmzZwUUoUg8RSoCWwFXQVGS6TT3/fZXGSDzd38qTjp1qTph1HjhguLz8HyqUI4kur17f/NbPrvidGpra7jrrl/KnI7ExFM1oXgG3vIzTldGDRjudXZ18shv7uP8C7/M7h07vTWbtkiCwjN8Bj7b5 kZC6skRroqAQfzHhkonl2G3CtJxHsAGASYQCswbChkstDaCl/ 8gXEe NECJM6I8XqP67iK/UXctM9N/GPpvw9KG 9s1I/7wtfer085B43dvRA/CEfGcvEyljgeriuS94yiaeTlJSXOVLQ1x1PSFUKoeccYeL644mEsFQFwwPyruwTUhYXFJHu68d2bVkcKZSeqlqO46BarnCE4vZ09TmK4yFDGhXhGF2pPunTDCcYCNm2azuW5Ui/0NOulNISnoOm2LpUpGK5ruVTVd3zPMt2s66hdmC5eVUROprqKtJWXNdDOorrMwzddaWtCpFyNemk09n3zlr  XceeuT3zr8E5XDDAWXm1PFXfu2842668munEIkJMDzwnGM/qsB1HdQ8yM40nqKgxkJkPRvXdQlkPdy8S65cRzclUigI18MybYSlIF1QhYqiawjbwdE0MDQ0BxTbJe9TsF0H3VbIl/gIZEBLWNhFAs/OoPflsUoDyJyFYmgomo7hKGSzWQxLhUCAvADPMAilTFzVJRdQsZHgCVzXw7ZdhKYTT2TZsv0I993/yosXXHzNWZd/ 9v5jwTljFNPmlMYbF9z350XQ64b7Ax4LnjHNo3rU3AMDV8ftP/8KXI9SQJTRuIOKKNQDZLYdpjsrgaqL1lO 5Y9VAwYQMbKY21poG93A7WTRtGxaz lM8aT2XoAo66SihkTObp7B qMekKeQK47TPuhgwy/ SJUW6fhB/dijKsnNKSanY tZMLXlxPI5PGPG87 dZsZfvxcPrj9cfr3tTDh/LNpe xFikaOQRVwYMP7jP3BeQTHVICWBBRQJJ7n4mCg arZuyfOWefd8NQvfvX4OUuXLZN/AUU986wz2bdvv/rb39z8x9/ddUlNNJBGsdLgAZ6GJ1RyfgXNFei2DpZH mA7pScdT8OhJrKdScpSWexkkvzYCo40NGN0Z4ju7ySuQF6mGXL6XEyZRB9dQ3RwBWRMTL HL9/P0X0HkKKQsj6P/kSWXFUZqeIoub4MZnsORfro7IlTXluPe6AdWRghVFLD0c17qRg1lK6tDQw67zhSjU0YmkGf7mD6UpSfNongiCJUz0VxgmDp4IAiJarnIU1JeVUt4UBs9G8eeK79nHM/v0XTtGPBcfmKZZx1ztlFc dOmlFXFcG10oCCp/hB8aN4On5boEqBVBQ8VcXXkyW5u4lqPUZpa5xkaxpr8DCGn30u9WMn4ogQnXt7MewAWVPQ1taFMMJ0t/bRZ0r8wRJ0XwF2IESpHqNozyF625vwJlQx8rwTqR1YTirbi7ZwOAO uBClKMbgM06mP5vBVgQEVFxDReoaImVj7mnH1sA4dRbDli3EnxFkDnTi2B5OwADFAwXwxLGPrbgIrw ZOcwZK2aS6mu9c9/u3bG/nhi5TIZ4d49XVVokhSrQHQlSIFFxhYcrPCwRABnA8wK4WoikKek 2kqwoAQrJZAZCy2n0X7LH4lvbQC/H70qhH9/G6E yG0/DBlJbtdRnJxN72vrMfe34xWXEyopp8 SKH05IvkQDfe SHZHBxHbQORsRDhIWrEhJMkoDqrigGFi RxU18bJZEh90EDedunbvpfmh17Gzjmk1x/G67FxDQ/XSIKaByFBEXiug6I6KEqKYMhk7LjBxlsrXx/5V1D27z/MhRd9LZTtiwscG6QATyCFhxQOnmKiKnlw8wiZxVXiGOMLGfOdz5GOZfHX6 TTPYSVnAyNr5HpdBxPNbFqIvT3tuKNKGDUD7 KHFTE2EtXUDl MOEF41GGVeLYaUy/RKssJON4OJpFYMQAUnmJzxfAl9Nof2kzwTy4PWmKsh4FMgRumFBWh6yP6OB6hl93GaFwjEBxKUbUT2HEYNyNXyFcF8V1TVw0TFXHVSNADLwiPK8QmwiuVAiGA2zfsT0C4HkeWjAYJBaOaJmMDaqLFL4/e4mD8BxUVDwPPF8AF4nPzBI/0ELyp08QqCmS uihiPRBEo1NsmFdDwVDq6SZt/BVlwgnmRPp5l42XPcwVaV dnX1UjGoitLBRZjJHP62DjI h9DgetjVwpF9B0g3xhl25jwiBWXs dUj6HUV ItirLvtcQYPHcLRN7eiNvTiNLTR1PEyfS1H2XL9QxTVV9C eQOlYQPLL9h39zOM exCwsOKcfNp3LCHKl2wFBQRAMdBBAHFBs9FiIAEUBQFraurk/5Mvy00AToIzYdru2h5B0UX4EockUBTQdGDEPBTumAiuUZHFo rl0qdz1EHlJPN27Js135GLJwuEr1JES2NIaeNkMmeXi1xuIVobSFl8QiR4gixwXUUSI9Udy/ iB tOIIxuASRyxD/oJGyabVQGKH29CmEBlVjBAIcfDNDxfIJdK1SIOynesRonI6cLBo1SvQlcrJy9hg8L0uwpET6Qj6RPNKKETKEJxVUNURi9xHaVzYQ9CSeUHFtjdiAEBXnnIR0HVRN ythUyorC iNZ6q e kprdddMRPzUAdGcRmK5oBugxDkHAefGMiOve3sbj5AZazUUe2wk3FzjunLO2HP56ioUhcqOSFFUNU1W6D5hSp0XTf8UhFC00EXCFXFNPNIy5Z w4flOZiqS1BoUvqECEpIOhauImQMXToqQlMV4TMMIfO20HRDKkipqTq28KRiO4igIXOehW65 KQifCgIEJYfESzxI5SUyCW68TX3E39tG23bDzNo7lSOHtzPxN9 j/Mv T3 8Jg59/7 t sAtHg2jSVlHtuVJKVofHEtAaOYwuFlyMogOQ2KB0/k9VcbufBbtxJ3cdSQ3xGemhdSmtLL511P5oSqOVgS23U0AbrlSU0qnvCQQrOFJoQAxVOk56EoHgLFUz3huI7jKJoi89IVWtAvFNdGmK5U0BxXx3YVSVBTQyBCAjTDr0npuo5hGAKhkM/m0Q1N2ppEohD0XKGaUrNztqYGde3k5bPEtd8 RZQHizDGlaEbEWTGwO7oZ8Cy XiWje24hFU9/RdP0XyOgm1LCyHyXiQUNIYPoufd3fQ2HqBg/BhkSKF06HCefvMNOf kU V3r/2B4xlqHlShezIgHVM1Ham50nWQSNuyNNd1hOXYVt62c7bjCEPVdM9D4klc6SEEridx8DzpWo6tCSFTVp5AKKjapi0803IN3cDVVSdv5qTmkdeEihEORMJGQJiOrbmeJwSe8FBAKihCkY4iMXMm2XRauo6T37X7gPbgb /2lwaFc8NFnxEHH39W5NKSYECjX2gMihUgbHBtF8Pn yuj1YJBg7ztKq6mCE xSGQSFE0bTd3kcaghhXRfN7adotc0WbxknjNu3Jg8YABBPt4kIPif26cZxwHSQ6sKrQfuv8U4r7pCxNfsYsrPrkCIKB0r32fX755kxt3fxzQdFJS/gZKzbGxHoiEQikpsbzeODzpffYRcRRS3xMeAi1ZIIxCVrqc4gOV5XlRRlP9kYn9diGVZ e7ubgfQdF1HVVUZiUQwDEMC5HI5kqkUnvSEIpDBYFCLhCPGn8f4NMBqgH/c1KnpxG88EagfLkYN76Lt/teFjJRBV5yh55yArR7bPorQ/vaHA4YMpvlIhydMB9rTdK/axcTTz6J172oYO5PY6AEY0pOGKhypSAfwK4ryiSZ54MCB5COPPLKlvrbGGTZsWEiC7O7tze07cNALRsOm5lPNzuaj7uQpE9TykhKfFo6pLW1tvj1btorhQ4faZ5997lBg4KcAxsjlPdcwpZPLp7Se2ogINebIf7AflCAhJ48IaXiKQjDg/xsomzfs5NrrfkJf01oIR4gtncGejRuInTybTM7myEtvUTqmHtXzpJnLaUD4k8yqubnZeX/7ju5LLr2kvLK8zJfu7xeZvMtoXXPmz1/oXXH1FVZ7b6fzxP1/8EqLdMDz9cc1bcKwicqE4aNyDz96X Lqq3d0/vjH15X6/f7wJ0XFFsikYll6oWdUtSscbu4Cq5/oqNEESoswLfA8ha3b12Vuv/Xnx8ibpmkY4aCX11WwsjhbGymdOB2xfjORITWUzVsgRTRMPmcBivwkE4rH485zzz8fjxYWRGKRcPm PR8YimKQsyQ v4 RwwfJReNHyIbdCkE1InfvPygKQzpmzq/5QyGE5jlfv/iS7MlLlmdqauo6L730UglEPxEoluX4UFSvuVdaqw7ImPSEU1yC3tlPflMDRWNHHts WNamDetxXBcNwMnmUT0FXDAQOG6WsGKQCvpQ nPIvIUQCpoQzicJemvXro3He7pt18nGWluO GvrBmmBcBTXA12BbKqFSP8Raroa2bnxfeLCJu3zMX3uLNZsWIstc1qqo18766xzjJ6enn4g/0lBCTrImnCBJxJJ6E5Qu3QutkiiNiSw9rWjega2ZbHk IXpUSOGYdnWMVB0T4i85wl0jeyYSmrnT6HZSTNi QxaVm4SbjKDYWjIf5AuP84mTpxobN262a2uqBCqqomjrR3UD4kikejCpaNpD mj25hY6mImj7D0jM8d87D2ToTuIWyD9uZeUVtdo1mOpQGu53n8h0EegJxPiJ6gAtUR0TswLIKTa9DCEM9vwTYVYkLieUikyCOPaUcCIOT365btGKRNEu9uo7 hgYZ164h3dpDevhfFtBHHlDftk5wEtbW10dKSEp dt9m/Zx8lxcWsXbseVVHwsOnv6aCiPETOOUw8cZDfP/cUv7v/PvrTSarKqzBzLoYRpLOrk5kzZ6qA/glDitAcqXmpjMrwKlFy3ASa3tzKwRc3k8lLqk6cied5SA/HFzEUf8yPP Y/tkDbp4sONw8 g3GnnIRMOUxasYz0wU6KZk9GKy/FZ6hCMzTtk05q2IhR/lTOkp1dvU7AH3CmTBrvKHiOoniyO5GQXiwqq2dNp6nlCAumT2PpyUs4cOCAVFUf /bsJRwLIaUnBw8e7AdKPomXAOg Qw jab7GPuHf10tZc5qixj5K l2so92oNriOlEE96EX8EcK 8DFQSqMF0qdoeLpCj5bB7OpBW7Uf2Z0gQRxUD/AwdP0T84Xx48YbHT0Jx5GedbS5ySqMhKxDB/Y7 bzjqL6w0 L45H61StpeBYW Aqnrmpw97zhpaD5HStMxZdaaOWuG0DQt/GlYn5PLaYoiNSJ  lJJEZ5Yh2/OOFxdw0nkwTBQwDB0Q/cZfnyG71hMGT9itPve26pjaZYWmTkMDqVpfuFt6j53PqFiA3w6fl3Dc UnnlRZWalWUlziSCzzYMNepXbAQNHbfVC8/eZtWkgxtWf/9LboyUqxZNGJYt3bL3CopV9OmjZP7ti TtZUlDtFRWXa9OnT/J WGadzeUP6fcJNp0RHbycV559A7ah6mn/zJ3p27KVsxQnYjhSKJnRFU1BccQwUFFxbSkuTlpbZ1IaVTlF1xTn07z6KXhKmbMJI3HweTfl0jP24ebP9b737bMvug/1ywIB27cbrvq1e/jXFmFQ3yGfvqjcyQmonntXBfY9eQ29isWxsaXV2fvCG87Uvf9ObMH5ysapqnzpVsBUhTOGK2OiBVEwaQ8db7 G299Gd7KZuyWQcTcN0pBUtDOWKSqPk8 Yx9BVVeKYncVwHfdNeBtbXUrt8IXXjhsK2/WC5KIqC58pPNbmx48aGx4yaFYuES7o3rl3druXz3XZPqHfVc /3ja7rSw0q7sgc WB/9rTF8zKN zYn3lv3Wk9j04GO9e9vTBeXFGn8D8xQBAHLw4wnCRTXUZEM0vrAm5QPmICMhDFVF0WIpFCErSgqQqhouXQaiaeYpo00bfD5iSd6sTZtJtvTi61rIF3wHBzH/dSTW7zw MqRwzuyD/7m8Y1f/tr3CDi/jk08XilUrCPh4rTmbzgaUZ58fr25YObZ9qyli/VVq1eyYMEC43 aSfotj6imk3Us ju7ybs5Aj4dp6UTNxYhgsDzPFfTVU/XVVxXRWs7dAizLynjfX2OrXhEpo kd9tO2nbsIqAYFI8fjBQKxYUF Hz6RwYVz/Pkf5IPVVSUDv7edVfEheK1Pf/QvvSOI6/nKitl1FLxm1qZN3jiJPWS71071B8Mlp500uL/jewaD6TjOgRVTYqoKsyKEIVDJ2D3JggGoghPgERRFFcRwkEIGy1YUozfcjxpOdJzwJUGZmkRim1hKwa2COJ5ivQUz1EU9SNd c AfCzTVVUVYCooLDvvzr7Vb7 wsz3ZbOZSnhaqrOfrF55U7/MZ5fzvmeyyM9KN QXbDtP13EZZtmCM6Ni6Ef/YQfS/8C5VC bheJJYNEphYSH5fB7NMS1c05Y2SFU30BtaKSwrQBk5ALr6sHbulSpTSGcysvTfM9pP9GUVhYIFi5bN 1/UXJJ/1nn8f/9L0zKRiirUgqgoHTtE1E2dQk9Oo2TOZFrXCzAd8DxQNEVRdBTFRXi6CroqFc zzZ4ETRu3EQ1GCCZ6Cdke8eY27L4 R9N9MpvLC/737X8ypozH4z0HDhzY3tDQsDqRSLT/k6jiIcOuJ91hpfSU ml9/V06euPsWr0OO2qgu6B4iuZKV3FdF9d10XxCYKgCO 9KjADa GqaNrxPyFUg5aCVBaUaDkrTcoXtOBr/fXOA9J 9QAOc3t54du/ePbmm5qb 9zduSsZi0fT27dvFVVddJefNm/chwIXjOgHL0UoryvFGDqD3tfUkk3lqx0wk3rCPCkNDeji6qnm6ruE4GlqoMkKIjGfmPccTQYqmjcba3opv4wFUw5DRYWMh5HcSqawo8T7VV7X vKBP7AWWZbXecccde0PhoP3Zcz5XfKSpObhpy2bZ19/PgIH12syZs SUKVPDb65c6VuxYkVa0z4iDdGEdII md60l0N/eIfquaMxOi36N yh vgx2FYeCUJaBjLvQ5oeWkC6BGyp4NM0x/BQG7uIbWshU1yAPWkQbliVZZYldVXFsqyP/6yOI3fu3NmdSCSk53n9U6ZMUQsKCoZ ClC6W1tbVj/91EvBvj6l5Nln3vSNHTfA OpFFwQGDx4iDCMgALl69bu5pqYmKYRQxowZ80 nY85zZZdioQ2tlENnTkV9b7 gLUVo hD6Nu7HOOUzqEKRoYiBEQqgGqCp0sAndcV2XVWE/RSOqmW3nUeJhHGTcSqitSihEFJ65PPmx64kn89b69evbzNN09myZUs6GAxWzpo169Nsm5imqbH5C0707d1lRZOZjkhLuxm2pOYzjADgysZDR3JrVq V119/vfmre 7Jl5SUfARdUIRfIoXfL7vUtAhEFZKhIHoxhFQfMcCV0tOEeux2UFURCAU0IQxP0bTWFAfueJIh08Yy4fNLmLBoNt2PvyNyh4/gCwb4TxLUUCgkli5dGho/fnygt7c32NPTk/vzCfOJeZeqaqVlZQVU1Rdp6Yzf39VW6PvxtQ8bG7fsNDykeOqpP8gVK07Lq6qaLiwqStbU1PzTDYPhKVrEVRwn7xKqrmDQ989i4CXL8RD4p47ElA6u6znouoci8DQDDS2M1Pp0N 8aXoGf8HmLaN92iMT2g/RnTEKTRuCvKRfScYX3H4hMiqIYAwcOHKCqavucOXNypmn2OI7Tp2la0SdFpbi4RA EcQYOM T fVEy/WXYZlL86ldPyDXjwnLchNHOqDGj7H379qXC4bCn63rknzxX2o7lQ p TRoosmnDVtG7 Qj1aQ9lUBWma3OMZTkKnoN07WOBU9UN1xKK5aBSWVlLRkljhAxGnrdQ1H17GUrIJ3RNFXnT/E/XY1iWFamrr8Pv9yOldD7N/vH5fNGRIwe5xSWKOWBQgYPISYRfNjXl5Dvv7JVTp823gVxHR0d62LBhsY 6i/KkNB1Nc11MmcpnMFVktLaI5qBKPtePfqx0pVBatg9FQ1U0xPPPP8/RIy1GQA8I nI03/IYVQV1tK3bS9 ew3i9aYHtCA8F1/nP16aqql1aXCI0TYuoQoQ/5XFcPXXSTF8 ZeWmz6q1/AXNEn fLCwaIs18hbzttoeddDprHznSnKupqVE/6gTzpHS0rE2gOMrwE8cxfM4IhnzpOMZdtIDw2GrSPhc8rz8ajpgv/ek5mlvbEbt27gxe MUv359K2gU/uf912icMJ9fSSTQSov3d7ex5ciVuOoeuqZ9oNblcDlShR6IRtbOrqz2bzf790WXF4/FO0zTz/xik/1F3jkYLBgwaOMJIJTvcJUtHycISS3Z0JUgkot7GTe3cesd9rqZrSnFxcelH8oFMXmrSQfo80tLF0V2Rz/ei yLERkzikSdepyeRib2/bX/xN678DpZpIUJBf9GOXTtWpPMZfvNcM/fHBYXfOIOhd17MyB fzsgvn4gajglVUfhPIu1f4o6m66ri9/lXbXgv9LObb 452tKS/nOC1vPqypXrvv/jn2w53Nh0AEj3JZPZl95648ATzz25zXWd/D8MOeyUk08YodhSjBxQQ1WpIJvrRioFMpkrkCvf2eZUVlSVKooy7KOvCTUUDeF4Fob0I6RAE3ncwgHc/etN/OzaZxkyZHDwkku  0JPV8eKgN9UhOOY2pwxPqYM8lGke7y4bjdnXHITnf0JdE0iLEfg2sJ1TfFJ1NFUJsUfn3wiVFJeGll44glFUlGcRF9f qHHH tq6 4OLjh YZWN1NZt3tx /x8fbVGigVQ6m012tHc0/WWMlpYjXQf27WpvPLQrM3Fkob7y QfF Z9dIsaOLEdTesHpRRMODQcPu//qhHM9KTzVU3QlLwwzKZS8ih4cxfV3v8iVv7iXESOGkWrZz4QRuckVkeAzrhPya65UsjlTcuqCKFYqxa6kxvt7s3zhi7/i0d98mbKSGGgSj/9MS1EUJb97397Op1983r9g0cLA9NkzRcOBw4F7H3vErK r7R0xalSgvq4 sn3HDu3O  9VBw4ayPzFc1095NcP7kAoivgra37sodvbtr/zVDYc1YpC/kAs2d2nvfzkXeLcMy XTzyzifaOTqesJMqOnXv60ul0azgc/ieSaHuW4XoSxXNA CEwiB/87Flu d0bjJ4xifihw8we5WPQiCjPtPQ6oHjijLPO6e5zK3//7vajLF5UzpACl4hSwK6mApad/2sOtacl/giBQOg/ovgtLS3pl157zTx52TK1oLzEeGP1234CejhWURobPXVy7J31a4obWo/EQiWFkdGTJobHTZ0Y/v2jD4YSqWQkZ9tFrutFAGzHdrDagsX 3pIYnRHDbvZVF aNlv2b ONDd3LaKRPl2FElXiSkcqSxyWpuPtL Ucmm9Gyh zQDpUgQHsB1t7zIzb99k0kz5hE/vJ9po1Tqh1eyal07C5ecfFP9wPq8ePQPj7Fg6anXNCZL7np/axefmVZKfSCOYvg5ahVx1lfupK1Novmi/xF5a2lvy9UMHuArrig1Dh1p1nbu3WMUlhZrp5y2zO/iBZvbWv0Zy/SXVVb4Z86f409mskZPb9Kfc8xgKBqMaIYWOhZ0s8LOdkcCmhlTvXxIyJxfeP2iOOpj/tzJMp44bMViWLrhZeN9fTm/z2/8RfD6kOdKVw1HioUTGMZ3bnpO/OLBl5k6dx49jR weIRkdJ3Bi6uPsOuQ oCIRq5/4OH7UYUuStase/PxIcMGfG/r2sZwfdSeNGV8hKbuLjwjgkaJ986b62Ta1gjHytSTTlryb5O/g42HujoSvb7CyvJgZU2VMXrcWMVDKHkzr6iaJqbPmCGCoaCwHEfx8ERBQTFzZs8VvqDB0UOHxIRho7VwKKTlshnv3dfuFV5/hyEUxVBUVIRQk7mQd9ySc/PLzz7bEZpqlJaUGWeeeWbN2HGjx/w58UwpivKXChz57qp3c82HDyqHWzL6bfc8q86ZO4uOhq3MGmkyslrntZVdyYYecWEm5z5xoHHvzM548z7thEWL/Z1N2xaF7O53bem1tuRMyrUuTpsR4tX3DmNqI0hZBfK1597iG1eM/ThBSAtHwj5V11FUge1KHAG6glCFhnQlLhJFFUhXIvGQjhQquvSEq2XN5LF6VSCZTNDf22NEFEVIRUNRbYGiSlcaoPpd0CJzZy8o seTz/M8/99fmBmGn9ff2sbmXb0sXvQZju5eyYLhKeqrBX1mEUd7fLIkKibOnFTzk0NH0 8J0/uTmD51Woed0d4ti6q1CxeHZ2iFLh4eETvJ8jkBDOcQ/ckcUybPszzpfVwOI0oKisr9IUPLk0PioKgauuOhKBJbl2hSw7DBp2i4wkJVXISiCA1d ExPYB8jiB2djdiup7lGRJiGpkkVoaKScwzpD0b/VZBHCPEhmcJFlbo/JiaNHcvBbavk7PEWI6sdlGweSyoUFYmCk2dWX1EcyAwsjxUenjt1PmLGrFnOxVdcc/Ib69qf1v0qI pUFNPFFQqel2TJrAICSht7933gBEOhj03sHMtxPMXFEjkQEkWoQhM6iiexDRtP NBc0G0VNAdXyWPrJqoawqdGhapr4rmnH axu38m8mlEnxsT8YwgkVFxTT OLmhra8SRpP4sQP17EmlZeArED69h8WRTVFTmyNoehqsRpp9FCypoi2dYtzN/cPbCE2 75FvfQTz33LNVDz7462 edvwZF25fW/yDgx/4UTUPiY10QFUSLJofprbcIZfNyn joySPtB/ddTTe1mFmXOGThUJzffg8j76AwHEFobwgo1ukoyqOUBE5HzIQo7 /n/5EH2p9Lft7O7jvwbsQnW1EMNHMBEHpR1WH4hrFoiLSw3OP/Uh54KGHMkD2Y WdXNoLWHExf5Iiaktc6WY9XKlhaQ4EfKzfk RQvuKpUbMXnfTSm6/V9ffHEbZtG8l020/T7H9einw0EZdSESp/ubCQTk5qspWp43wy2d/9LyfRF 9tufqLX2h7/Jc3Sc 01CJfGQfXbOKxK75DfP9 9EiQYMrktetvoPH119ACAs2Iofbk2HjrXay88x4SrT30NXcQiwZpyvTjhgQlAYOsGqS7PQNujsJsh6jWsuLwnh3i6RdfPZzo70//O/VOmlkWTPaLutI0fmHiw0B4Cg6QdSS7d/dgON2NburQrdlM8vsFBYVoo0cPbCotLvle1m64cfp8e56adpGOjiolCBfFUYTh2oS1nDzSdDjhuK5fU9V/ykatZMqZkujX/QcOiQMJi6rhI4Xb2yHGr9vJ3u6fE/7F99F3H2DKOxtxNmxnR9Zm0jnn0vrU28xctZmdqmRrPEHNrAWkVu9g5vBaOgwL17KoTvgwDJ0EcUJaEKtLpWHXSnX/vkP982ZNSkDsXyWcUlVRCmIKAc0TirCFZ6g4rodQVXKew9QRKtNGZL6z78gRSoIFV6uahdafcKmvHH3f0X17u8sqW383eqDA7vNQXQNFz2EITfqElDGfEOlE0nNs19HUf04OPWmLatvRj tKqludg LN224SitXPZVmb/fsOseXOX1NuOpzY3oFpe7z81DMcKIphvvkyy1qbKSkvYFN7M4fWvMPnPT DG0we6c1TVuJjdnMXh6MhXg5rVDjFVLXnxViRJF4W8UdC4cC/2z7pXEqoPk0oqg/dSOOpDrorwNIJahZTphaxe1 O93Ymb11w0ojbtm55Eq29pSX45so1b48fOelynxzyxcMNb/9mVJXrV0wdXQVVKMJnaPgVMAxD4e9o IdDv2Z4QtOiblbM6LRF75ptrLY60XImE/MKPWt2kQ/pRJ00PtNjfGMbj934cxZms0RlnjIrzaBMEt/mrSy0LBKpJBMj1dR90Mik3hSWUoTaHmBWSmHA0aMyEZHewapBBPwfx7QVYWiGMDQQOngqONqxRFFDsnZzkt2d4SsTju FjTv3DZy8ZdABITTpDh9eUhyItK/asXPXZf09ISGEjqpb HzgD7rSF3DQg1lcxRR43kdOwggXFLihUrUfV8ScvJybcpgSK8RFUmSbjM9o1JfVkMdF91xK pJMzCtMTUtsCcG8xSSCjPSgMN0HIsnYklIGo4N08Pl9stLJy1EtB5xKs99tVb18vqIs/3EUwacaIigEQSOD33DQVTCCAleX2Hohhw9LouQGDiovWC0c3xUXX3IXmoLilpSqvaPG5at9vt7JEQyECprq4fOBobvC59fw5wMIV4h/dWccKykK5soLtYzjSRTwzCSqDKIUxZAdPaiKidAErgImCkYoRFSoxOJJpIBoTlLSlaW7SMHp9fDZDlnTxtY1bMC1VGJ T8Y8U8YNn7WvelBu7uw5YaDg35FJ1xXSp kYIQ/XA7/rJy8U3JADeY8xtR4Thomvi8hAdrQqPa1tTYiqygp015MinWPsEIvRw9IEhEtINwirCgU6skBTREwrRNo56UrL Xvd5K eoqtGbNIwtS8SxvUU4TMzDPFF6FEFNgqKT5Lsi6PbKgoeOccjFI7hKS5SQNh2qbJtEoYk54CjGvRnPELoWMdUbMIiJLOWcFpiUUcdP8WbPG5s7ccwbGFZptB0Ben3CAQgIqFIVYioNtXBBCvmewysSGGmmxk3eWLH3j17EeWlJdiptAjYNgWaj6hhEPUFiAbCxIJBCkMqZTGbgiJHJJU0qUz6r81C/ziBcQtP9W8pq6TP5xPFrs3g9jSeKAZhoJpZcvk02WgEGwXLyhDI2RiqD5 rYOKh m3COT9 W4ARpNFNobtpECo9 TT bEqavoizKRzJDT7xpKAq1JKP2z6KmaBIy4uoYhNTISosYiJHTECMPEG/i4j6ae/vxXXUrYsWnYRWPaBKxrNeYt3uFAUxD5 mokmLoCYJBwXBgK5FA0LrcWw/XiSDp/8rAqcNmjql4tU5CzK7n36SWXYex0pxsDJGUdyPbqYpNws4GNaZmArj6C7ZXBLNMVClwMHFUdPo4TIcpQBVD5FW nEyvfSGfLLXn5dl2ZRsLAi5zcMHWmceP6f833nJn8tDpON5Iq0Ua6YRxXPTeMEibMsmK/uw9SAZS D4NWxfjocefqh5w/sb0MLRCnn93Y vuO2Xd52YwSmK5/Jh13LCMuOERFLmPc9rTmVyXYqdm5vqMc83HGn9q0oBXYjoqd 9UnvivTUUHzVFsW2i5hIciQpmd7nkUlnWFcNI3UCSJRY0AAWBQGiSPmykmiFrBOnVNMrsPnRT0FxVRa8nmOg4vFEWlSddeXVpSVFR b TRD3PyyqK4kh/gf WJ5qoXqM/r1jeKgNbcV035umuP2dZPX6hOVJauq kJvvzm3/YVVgQPlbztnDRgvjCRQset4Fsto/e7gShYIhEXyfJviRbtrQwe aEP33pvM8O70n1zimsLM7 qxr9wcOGGSfcfZd884tfEsu7 sWk3hwHq4O05TKEszZF9SEOVzjgGPQgybkmfiRduodXUkVdZ4KMP0hbWGdSIkc2FOOgL0i5CMv3PEsO  blgfmLFhf8Oy9RFAVFUYKAk3UxvnrZjy4dP778V587 yteWZGF8Bz0sEJfSqEyFCHdl W0ZYv44vkXf7gMwgFyuSxm1qKqvJLiwiLqawdTVVXH0CG19CSavbyMb3TcfBSwHEh2Zq38kUTS8j6sj2pTFi7WTnz4YV4bUUnCr2NYft4qCdNvRBh9KEubTycerkbaEcyIjzwK6aIYCdNPuWmwt0xQmBdE8kE2VVSQKRR8YHcQuuLL4qwvX/yfFjgLwChQFKemrPQJQ4Q9QwMFF1WA4nkoSPBczDxYZh7rzxm69vfNMRF/gL7eOGUlx peNE2jpjpITXUt8URcsaU2/qlV2ynswbALA862bY3Z0kIhdNfRBlcNMEaUxbQJZSUiGtBFbPgYdi2ew2tPvchMC3xVQ3iGLDPyLjFfKetkFJ8iKIw0MVqG2WcU0hcpoUlXcbDxdQueKiomO3U2WjyBfdJ4Ubj8MvFcY58Vcq2 kpCu X26tB0s1bHsqrICoalCbW7vNXozSVFeGNNGlhT5MWV29671luGbyjevuJQ3V77J4kVL eJXvojjeuTSKZ7948PkpI7ruqBrfwNFSpsXX3ql6L3179UVFxWIcePG9Zy45MQjoP4ZdkWYStH47Y7KzJoyo8KnGGctGC9LC6LkzazY0ZMVzzW1cPsffilHDoiI3T2H2GY0EP7iYBKZOLKrg44ijQffbWdKIsPBYaXs6W/mM4NizIqW8VyiFyuzixFOIWMdjT/Wd/NWzMJwVxGNlVBWPYV7Vr8pKtsUbUbN8Fyywujdls5mLDeUJt7hDAn7tHK/GqyM6DEj3RsaU1sRHFpSRL9mOyMHD5YjRg lt68XT4SprR/M8OFjAMjm0kyZ9hsSiQSGrn3YU371q7tKXnzl1Q12Njv48IEGotEi3jz1jXnXXnv9mkgkgqbgi2FX nIJBjt57cS6Aby45QPZdKiDC2cMFUPMFJfefAvb5CGxPiTpUzvQh0q6LIcWv4MI11DaESbl9LFS0xAzdLTSetYYNm85KWzFh5b20b7X5MWGFiIn1aLUeqQ7esmaWdHWeR8V jgtuivIkT9lpDZ mDL385/X/PWVgZ07097iUbVqb6LXEF39gSoL//yhgw1w8Ky0f Vba4XpCF576RVMM09zc5P 8ksvBSzT9CZNmZiqrw9TWFj44dKqZDIlNm3d/4uKmprBZ553Ds  8icGDBnI3l37337owQfmWYDrSj2s IKfW3Qc84cOEJ6HGDZhhDZqzjgt7Q8KPEOMHTdBDFQrsB5vpvZwiGDWRcXG6KnBetmi5ZVdcJKKcyH0j8uRq0vTXtNIuqoNp1TSN9KhfUWGyAVFJA520PdoJyUdtSi2hxbqE1iNovnwRq2y3PF//5z5wcm5eMTdsLlwXCBfEMskY6OlHikoLg1uLfNr73a3CekqpBKZ4LKTlhV 6/JvEolGyaTSQ9eueXf/9df/uPuhh 7vevDBB360d99e/R/77FAURWk 0nxOItmJ42qsWbWFVCrO7CljtY4jm1a2tDRVlpVUugmFLb95/k TU2GDEs9hU3sr3VqQZ7p7 fni47n G9/j5nuuR23vQk1FyKeGEKwKUeIEGTVvPH/Y8RjN1c1kfTlKOoO4CZNMRsGwfEjVJlimkS3R6SvwUWbYnHvi YSGTWD9tldIB KE1AAjLpgopg8aoY2dNFJUK6VanenJnfEUm3Yd5GfTp4oGNyvWN/QIKx8ShidI5xxqa pOjUQid/v1wIDqyuqXBg8dNHDMuPE0NB1EUX0/fuH5Fz4YOWLks3 93TxWUxKkICDTRxuOBgcUnkhT01E2r93EpAF xo2OGTvefmX68vMuea2iuubRI 3Nk0uKYhT3Zzlz4jSCBVFsB6IapNN9/HHPK8Sn2BjpOHWt9UwSI1kwaRgnLP482370AQd3JQgGLNSjaTRVI1A0AgUdTetH7XFo2yHJmCbjzBK de4lNMVNsrsb6RF9 Eo9sXnvGl5Z8yKvvDSJL1x0jXh 92E6HZ3JxVHKi4OUKULcV7uYKD6BBULTUf1aqOHQgYLm5kON1dX1DBw8gIKiSrJ79/Ha629z mlLy//JU4Qi5OknLmg88/jKslVvvUDUF NrX5xMqWFSHhQc6Wz8koTXB1ZUxT 7ZCGv3n43lSJCUXUFwQCUlheyqj2J7VMoGFnDzpIN PwWfa39bOnZzxMvmVze1cQdX/oR6g3X8u62txk2YTAJ2yHVZqKQw9AVooEoo4vGkUoWMO 4E3j9QJxfPPJNGkr3YTkBkFmUEQ7F5QPElvVHxSWxsDzr CkcybiMiwaE8CkSJyAqbPfY8y9APN PP6Q7Bw7vLp4weSgH9xzi8Uc3U1BQR3NLA4lEnulTxof CRQUCKji6MCqzPSykwsJFdXQleilaXuaWEEJe48cnBE30x666kUVl90b1zF66Wc5/fOn09l6mN8/eDv3P7eKO395LxMYyurGZ8hN9MgO1/CGFNIfL Gu957ni8su5QvnnEeH0kmf3UUu74Bi4IWDRFyNmj5YNnc2A67 Gi9u3kNrf4qM3kdiaDchowAzkET6Hax9KU4dMZ9xJTFhkSFrdnJo3xFe7EqK2rKhTBg2CkWFnHBwNQfLyRj7P9g4YOakQYyujlJTE2HTht1c9NnTyMlyknbM 4cyU1DAs2TmsEE3Rf4siugDJYkeMnCVPGV Udlx HBBKGyYTd3NzD1lIVpBmIsv/wa3X/9DhtSN47hJNmcsmk/b/esJ7Qsi64rIticpbrQpEBqXzbiC5pZevvro12GqjRdTSBkm bCN4wi6HB 9nQYNb9/Oy8cv5VvHjeGJAwcJDFrKuIYoma4jdFVLvGo/4qjFtCVjufWGG1m94V3qh4zACKiEwjF tflhLvvaJZy8ZBFIGz8eTfsPTdHdfGlliUauuYlTZh/PkGiWSVMqWbPd4b1D8kPVSNpfcl09UtS 76jOsCFj0CMxOg/uoD bIRTMMTAitG0bVs7WhNdvdiVRA/DFL53D2k1rWbR4CVPmzKW7o53rrv0B37nqMpp7O/hgXxsTaiZx9heOo7q2gvrqITy59gU6B/Ugh7moOYESN7DTDvjTZKIurZVVlMWKSSXzmP4Me/p6mT/1s1w48HsQ7 APm1/mzc1vM6CmjBVLl7Ot4H3uvvVORtRP4Gd33IiTy3L2F1awevNbnLxkEYppY YdXv/T8yvOOGMaOhrVBQWodBIriIOrEm/vx eblv3n7QMsPeMrL95zZ/vy1a 8Ny kaRhJj1OmjERra2VIRTWPrH71oh0t7hHV9jO4roLf3ncXNQNqqRs4nN07NjNwQC3ZXIqXX3 Ls447lysGD2NweQn3rdnCPWsOUex8wORhUSZao9j77gcYhUHmls6jTqliW2oruw7tothSmB6qZeiQOoTq475ZUwCVfkfhjk0dyJGnMjo8gjMnDCcQKuCZV18lWlONHta54drrQPUYPXwCMd xy7J4X5re9hSxGpWxIytpaWghbklCpRWUoaMV1JDyPmD0mDG9HwlKMBg5dNXVNy0 1LDzrNt/eNHvLzzjeCPa3cnut1qor3I5a/70U9ff wJHG/K0NrURqakh29PFDy66gAuu/jYVFVV0dnRx6023YviDTJkzj8LyCs487wuUjBuG69pMihUwUCvh4IHdjJgymklDhhPAz0vNh1mzdydGbw/nTp JJXRWt3ZTVVhCiW2jaBYLF8/g9cOHKK0qIqAJdh3eR mQASwuiLFz51a2bdrEpRd/nZnT57J9 3YAXn7xRXJmlqr6gRSGMlRNLOSGlQ088geDuuqhdPcfZO2Oo1/9/rIhL/ 9RqT  Mc//tCVQFFR Qf97U0bCvNd5x1ZtZFKtRo1I5F2njHTphBv6ydvKzR1dFEaieDaOXoyWa666rs898yzNB46zKVfv5RvffNyXnn5JV54 kmuOes0xoaiNB1t4/HtB mO1WFnVWYOrCFtmzy3s5u1 QCuFuHkwSPx Xw8snMPj2zbzc7Du5k qAzZcJRVN/6aTfc9xIH31/DWypdoaWjEzmXp7u9i5ozprF 7nj0793LxxZfQ2t7B1y 7lKkTRzO8UnDCSUMpDmlMGTyOXYfauePBtejFQ0 /4IJvP1peViEDwb/d2nwIlL/0/La2tSprX3ns8qXLjqe4YCA9hzsJWi6hZB/jLziBHUcacPIe61evZc32rUydNh0rb JYNv19fZx99tmMGjOaUUOHcMnFFzFs0niiVYMxgzHK6isorCqioryIeDJPLBRkcHkhQ uLmDC4nJpoiLAUzKyvYEpdOQuHD0Vp6 P0c85l1pIT2bhpI 2NLYi8oKMryYLFi9mxfTNd7d3Mnjmfm2 9hdVr3 OznzuH8oFVVJWonDChgnFD6jiw/gPqRo5g0sxJ7D9q3vHd7990R1FxCWY2Qzga/eft8/fuM3LyzAEb3qqmcOpoGt/cjlZTRl9nC7WDh1DR3sSPVszlptc3E4vNYvuePXT3dDF58iQqysoYOmQwzz//PO ueodkuh9pezSt24M9ZAZPbN3JIAnfPn42QlX49cp1tFkW0weVc9lxM2jPpPnJE69jRkqoyMS5fPFMKmJhbnj8F8R7WrjssnPRZJxsd4KS4hIOHj1KMGgwYsAI9h88zPhJM7j5tru4  5bmDZ1DIoimTi0mGXzZrLnsTdpPdJJzagJ5O0EBbHIwz5dQ1EgVFHxYT3mowqGXdfxX3XZ U9efNqYU6sjFr0f9JJKOYTNHEq n56 FCXnnsMt973O/o4Uu3buZNTI0Tz91FNEozFcx HKK67gjrvvBuBH37mSH/7iZna4kiAOI9Rj36Mfwd68Q5Vfow4XEDTaCgfyHsJzmBDRKVXggqu we9vuZNlJy5i rTp9LkOllBRhMBL5/ErKlnTYvsHOznUsIeZk8ZQqKQ4c8UJjC1QOPTuasbPPYG9azZRNnUIuQEFXPidp tRQkeWnXIS37nq x8PSiaTYcbMuZG6SvHGQzctmVGQtug6bJE9bDHknBP44NZ7KKyuhEgND7S08vTqLcR7 hg1fCR33XUPw4YP49VXX XVl1 irbONPpnl7KWnUVVSQWFpOZ6mEu/uIdHbj2PlsbIpkq5LOBKkKhamvm4gRRU1RIqKifkC/OhHN3LDjT8kHPTz8COPMnHSVHTdoLCgAM xue/ 33DTrbdTUlHMiMG1VAqXS0 aQHWRRtuWLYTqx5Jt66Jm2jTaetvYJhUsY1Lp8KFDeupqayguKvp4UFKpFPPnzWff3j3GjMlVT/z6B0tPGxweyNrnNhG1TGrDEXq7e5BVVRSfPJsXVm3kmVc30iP9tB7t4bZf3MjwAdUcaTxEeyLBA/c9SO3AgXieQi5lEykqpbyuisP7d6A4KSwEx5 wnN54B2 89RTNjY3Mm3485cXV5DJZutraGD9lLKEiP1/80leorR4EwJGWFi79 qW8 fZKTlw8B8NLM6JM48unnkjfextRVAXraDeF9cMxnRR20Mf4r13E7/74 lunn/udEwoLYvITdWVJKQkFNauwbMQZ37hl029e2dPMvIsWUTNjOHHXQ/WHqR4 lH2/f5QFfovvffNsAgFJcUURV33jKn7 05vZvu8APp8fy7HZt3sv8e4EO3duw8z28v1vf43duzez9YPtHG1s5ozTlqB5Lg27Wpg1ZTGtbR28 95qNm5/j80Ht7Ls7LPwBUvBO1aT88prL7BgwXHs2rmHM087DZ0UF3xuHl9ZPIKAeQRdhcEnnUXBhJlkrSz5SJiRK1bw5hsb2Lyj4XeRcECaZi OY3/kEz0f3ULh92PoBoMGVrszj//CJbfddsf hnjj7d86cynJ9m58TpSDLz9PcayI3MFuql2NX54xlxteXcUhXwWvv7eFl95dzW/v/iW3/vIXPPvsM4SCQeYunEpdXT0trUepKKsm4A w9JSTURQYO3Ysxy04jvPOP49rrrkG27IZMLwO3fTTGu gvz9FcayEn/zgR9xyy885/oTjqCyJUR31 NyZK7Cb9tDbtJfYwHIGLp/LjuefIZu2mbjiVAonTOKxR17g4adX/bQ/6zw9Z848crkMp522gp/85Ccfv308z6O3txfXddB1jc5ECyUFlXz7sgsX1hSk3/rZjy gc 0 fJFCzGw/Pc9sRHXzBMZU4o4bz/f 8DqHmmwyXWkOtTZwwonzmTNnBo5jIz2XVH aVDKLYyqUFpcQKQjT3d1NPp/HdV1KS0tZt24dAX ARYsX0dPTwf6Du1l26nLeeHUtL7/8Bp85eR66L8XiGRWcNX88nas/IN1uguGRbu2kYvxgzFyc6oXHkQrVceOdj/W9vX7Xyffee/97t996O2 9/Ra2bfO5z32Ou/98IPxbT1EUhb9vKIoVFKEKwcN/ePbt719z8cizz79p1T03fbW8oL6Ypif2EygoxasKUzKihp1PPc vlp7Kk83t3Pend5hQNJ51q7dx0gmfYfnyU3FsC8PnIxQMEPAH0fS/iV6madLa2sr27dsZNWoUqqqSTWYZVTmUIDq33HobyWyOBQtnYrjdfOXMuQzzp lYu4ae/hyxgSMorxpJw8EXMeMe9UtPYGN3nKsv  HKIcPGnfmHRx/vLy4uJpfP4fP5sG0bw/jnTj7F wQPxVhmmp7ufTz1p9WRPz549333X/f5s vdPAfea6R25mL2PfBHigcUk852MuWiC3ls7Xbuf3QN0eJBbN62hfO/ch4//emP CTl7Jad54dXfo 7f/cQ46ZNo7jIpoxuLjxuLNOq6tj 5mbslj58UR8FowaRONpO6axp1C49jV/c/CBr39/zk5/cfMtPR44c5QQCx0pZ5s fz4YNG5g/fz6/ 93vqKur /Sg5HNJWo5uo6BwEEsXnKiofu27V359 o2nHTeLpue2IeN52nqOEinQUJIZ6hcvZV2in7sffB1/MMLGnTsZM34qjzz0ABXlZR/7/zZu3MjFl3yN5vbDzJl1PD4ryxnHDWJyeYru9Ruo9w0j1WFAUTmm1UtwUJjB5y1hR1s/1/340caqmgkn33DD9fuiRR/ujXrggQc4evQoX/3qVykvL/ fecpfQFG1Ui7/0kWcfM55PPPUg2eeOrfmyW98 VQOvbIWq8PEQqdu4jjWPPhbZixfQnzIMK6/5bfYFLJp2wECoQLuv/9 Zs6Y tEvWdg2d915F9f 6FqGjxzJoOF1lKpprr7gBIJdR9m1fisjxk5j/9sbKK8fhKkqlE2ZROXMKdz7xPM89MTK31/5rR9etmTRyVnbtvlHUP6vNUrn83nq62q493cPPfXbJ9dP Nb1D2WrJw4gNiZC/dxJNKzfypyLLqavtYVCpZdf3nAptbUBagaWEfb5OPnkU7nv4Yf adzd 3Zz/JLF/Oi6a1l06lLqK0sZHctwx4WnIDesJ93WS33FKCrmHU9BXS1GWZBxZ85HGzaIcy/9Ke salzx1GMvXrD8tBXZdCr1iRq3/segKIqCZVnoqsrc46bt2JsM1p/53Yc2GSOH46T2Uzu2mKJRA2lrSfD q uwmg9x89XncM7isRT6VCZOmsbll17GVVdeDt6x3qfnnnmeBcctoqm5hdM/s4RM/yFOGhNmaZnk0MtvYO7JoDsluH6d9391N54mGbRwHm/s72H5F7774ry5S0sff qp56pqav52pyyUT7y2/3FHuuu65PJ5zj338z2ptvScM75w 8O3fH/J2VOWD2Pv/fcTLC1j6mnLCFV4fHDfvZw5aiZVdcO5795XOWPRSTzzx6dpbWwgVj6A  99jDknHs/AijC 1GHuueZUBpk51t3yBFULjkMt10ntO0x42jjKZ85DnTiIH97/NHv29P7w2h/99MYTTlr of6bovKiD70J V8D5S 8JptOc/HFF1mjRw4797LvXtx RXvvN08eNoTw0IFg5HFa  hv6COR28gp557J0J dzTU/fYSZ02ezf9cuWtdt4jPLZmPaXQyM5Pnu5efS17yNlCJY8IPL2fbySqoWziTXl8SfzdBYV8u137rt0JgxM8544qkHt2u675 3wT/ULP6nz6H9rz3o4HkeeDBvwXz3njtu/9Y9Tzec/qu3DkAgg5ffx6bnnmfY8rMYUjuS9g2rGV0uufsXF P5shSOG8EJZ56IZTXwhXkhzh1bSOtLL2LuTtP89j5kbYjhy2bTc Qo4y7 HK94Gt/ 2e8f/dyyz4/76Q23fiQg/69epPhIy6T7qa2u9n5248 fXb03PfMr33zMSbTkGDJrLJ6X4siGTbi7Uhx4aBXajo3c8t3TGBjLEkk18/uffZ0TKstpeXMjoYJaDm07TLhyBLtffpfg8NFEBk/gC9 88 AfX98w66c/vv4LMydNzPJ/wf7XQVEUhWQyyexZ83j hZc2iNjY2vN 8PpOs6AWz ml/jPHQY PUE Iozv2E3/mSe696lzuuvpL2E1ttO7qYeiEBWS784RDIZSiAkZPOJFXn9rKJTc8 dtQwZCx1179nfdQ4BP0Sf/3Y8pHAQOQzWT45re 0bFv3 E5F/zwZ09ee/mSJWNVj 5qFZp6CVo Aq5Cw2PP0JeIUzFjCpY06GvrJeMpFJRXUj5uAtc8 DwPPf3yyfc/ IdXhw8fysHmD/AJ7ZO/D/j/EpS/lx9SqSQrVpyeKiwLLr3ysm985 tnzLrx OOGkjvUhZL0Y6kWRcWFpJs30NbcxoAB9bi9ScpnTORAr8klP7hl 4ITTj/ljLMDrZqqMHjwMVD b5rgv2T1VaXyoYcf/fljG1pPvfGRVRgVxVQtGUs73RTPnIRRUcmAKZNpOHgQvX4Ij 9v4/pHX7ljxORJM85ccVqroRvHKo3 C/ZfAyWTyVBdXcPLL7z UrRuxrRv/fbNvnwgSHl1EW/cfTt TMrGjqFo Zl86 k3O1989f1ZC bNuWLS IlmX18f3id84fT/C1AURSGfz6EogutuvG7TlONPql945tWvpYNVzDvxeGoXzOOhJ9/hS9fcfePmA4cGzJ875z0hBJZl8kkf0fz/BpQPJ05ZTjvtlGRv2jv1a9c dsvDmxq54PZH c719y0///wLrhk dFg l8v9V73j/z0oQDqdpqgw5txy2ZVXPbR6/9QBM48vO/30z/zJ0NT/Wuz4V/Z/BgAq6lR5PJ79rAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='

Comment: Provide the actual html you are using (not screenshot).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert base64 to image in javascript/jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227078/convert-base64-to-image-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @srk, don't cut the base64 string in the middle. Add all of it.

Comment: As already commented - add the complete base64 string to the question.

Comment: @Dekel i added base 64 string