# Howto save a base64-encoded image using node-red

Tags: json, image, base64, http-post, node-red

I wrote an Android app to send some text (which should be saved in a file) and an image (which should be saved as a seperate file) with a *HTTP-POST*-request using the *volley* lib.

The image is converted to a byte array. This byte array is converted to a string using *Base64.encodeToString()*. This string is set as attribute in an JSON-object which is send to the server.

The interface on the server-side is a node-red-server: The data is received and the file names and the text are extracted. So far everything works fine.  But when saving the image (which is a Base64-encoded string) only writes the string in a jpg-file.

What's left to do is decode the image string and save it as image. I don't know how to do this. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21227124/2699453) approach, but node-red does not know *Image()*.

Also I did not fully understand, why the best way to send an image is to parse it to a byte-array and encode this array as Base64-string. If someone could explain the idea or link me a tutorial this might help me.

Please let me know if you need my app-code/node-red-flows to help.

Comment: We can't help you with why **you** chose to base64 encode the image before sending it.

Comment: well... you are right, but most tutorials I found did it this way. So I thought it's done for a reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a base64 Node-RED node ([node-red-node-base64](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-base64)) that will convert a base64 encoded string into a NodeJS binary buffer.

If you run your string through this before sending it to a file node you will get a correctly formatted image.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. I tried this node, but I still can't open the images. I pass the image-string as payload to this node. the resulting payload should be the content of the jpg-file. Did I understand that correct?

Comment: I tried to open the files and my programm told me "Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x4c 0x7a)". If the image I capture is a jpg and I encode it and send it to the server it should still be a jpg, shouldn't it? I got this error with two different images

Comment: Assuming what you encoded on the Android side is a properly formatted jpeg stream then this should do what you need.

Comment: after encoding the image to a string I just decoded it again and displayed it in an image view. The encoding seems to be correct.

Comment: I solved this. thanks for your help, but it is important that the node takes a single line string as input!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. For everyone else who is looking for an answer I post this:

The [base64 Node-RED node](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-base64) hardillb mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46074736/2699453) works fine, but only if the whole string is in one line.

If you use the `encodeToString()` function with the `Base64.DEFAULT` flag like this:
`String returnString = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);`
Your recieve a multi line string. 
If you use the flag `Base64.NO_WRAP` instead it works fine with the node.