# how can i decode this long base64 url into normal readable url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using some image cropping plugin that returning a long base 64 URL which is hard to decode and when I am try its returning some long character which are `data:image/png;base64`, then some long string

Here what I made

## [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrqm7k54/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var src = $('#img1').attr('src');
    $("#image").val(src);
</script>
```

What I want is the URL of that image source in input field with original name and extension.

Comment: Maybe duplicate?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227078/convert-base64-to-image-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: where is this `with original name and extension` you require? is it conjured using dark majicks? buy the way - your fiddle is invalid and pointless - no jquery, and you've put a script tag in the script area! and you have no element with id img1

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrqm7k54/7/) at least does something

Comment: oh, and that base64 data URL is as readable as it gets - do you understand what a data URL even is? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs