# How to convert base64 to normal image URL?

Tags: javascript, angular, base64, data-uri

I'm trying to convert base64 to normal image URL using Angular 4. I found the solution:

```
dataURItoBlob(dataURI)
{
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    let byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
      byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    const mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    const ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], {type: mimeString});
}
```

But the problem is it changes the image URL format to:

```
".../public/uploads/offers/1531895217034CxqrY.blob"
```

**So I want to change it to normal format PNG or JPG**

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227078/convert-base64-to-image-in-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Your function is correct, but after it you have to use **[`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)** like follows:

```js
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI)
{
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString;

    if(dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
        byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++)
    {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], {type: mimeString});
}

var dataURI = 'data:image/png;base64,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';

var blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURI);
var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
document.querySelector('input').src = objectURL;
```

```html
<input type="image" src="#">
```

Today this will work in Chrome browsers fine, but in IE (and may be some others browsers) you have to check the security policy. Please see in IE the developer console. In this case please read about **[Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (CORS)**.

Comment: @Damitha, which browser do you use? Please check it in Chrome browsers (like Opera too). For IE you have to read the information at the bottom in my answer.

Comment: i'm using the Chrome browser

Comment: @Damitha, do you see the image after function calling? Please provide more information about why do you write "it's still not working". For example: what do you see in developer console?

Comment: this is the code 
`imageCropped(image: string) {
    this.croppedImage = image;
    this.BASE64  = this.dataURItoBlob(image);
    console.log('BASE64 => ', this.BASE64 );
    this.imageData = this.BASE64;
  } `

**this.imageData** is the variable that i pass through the API

Comment: this is the response 
`BASE64 =>  Blob(116234) {size: 116234, type: "image/png"}
size:116234
type:"image/png"
__proto__:Blob`

Comment: @Damitha, may be this new code has some mistakes. But in this case you have to ask a new question because I answered your question correctly and my code works. You can not ask 2 different questions in 1 question post according to sites rules.

Comment: @Damitha, if you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as accepted on the left side from my answer and then write a new question in new post.