# captcha image decode base64

Tags: javascript, image, base64, captcha

I need to resolve a catpcha image encoded in base64

I need to decode a captcha, but it comes to me in this format, they tell me to convert to decimal from hexadecimal and that the image is encoded in base64, but I can`t decode it.

```
{"dynamicParamData":{"name":"image",
"value":"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",
"description":"Introduzca el numero de la imagen",
"type":"IMAGE"}}
```

Comment: I understand your frustration but unfortunately SO is for asking specific programming questions not to ask people to write code for you. Please specify what you did and where did you stuck or better yet refer to the guidelines of how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert base64 to image in javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227078/convert-base64-to-image-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [atob](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_atob.asp) to decode a base64-encoded string.

```
let str = `really long base64 string`;
let blob = atob(str);
```

From there, you can create a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) out of the byte array. If you're just wanting to display the image, consider leaving it base64-encoded and embed it as a [data URI.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images?rq=1)

```
<image src="data:image/png;base64,ReallyLongBase64String" />
```

Comment: Thanks John but the problem is that it is not encoded in base64 as they say, it looks like a simple string, or not?

Comment: A string *is* base64 encoded. It's a way to represent binary data in a string.