# Convert a Base64 image string back into a file to send to Parse upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

Adding CropperJS into a nodejs solution, and I'm trying to get the returned Base64 string back into file format. So I can send the file to the upload function.

I can't change any functionality and need to use file type to send as a parameter.

I tried: Creating a blob and passing it -> get an error can't to parse the file.

```
//this is used to upload the file 
File.upload(file).then(function (savedFile) {


//with the new cropper i get back base64 string from:
$scope.imgSrc = $scope.cropperCrop.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL();
```

How do I convert imgSrc to file to pass into the File upload function?

Comment: check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227078/convert-base64-to-image-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: can you share code snippet?

Comment: @Raa i tried that but got an error when sending it through as a parameter.:
angular.js:15567 TypeError: Cannot create a Parse.File with that data.
    at new s (parse.min.js:13)
    at Object.upload (FileUploadService.js:6)

Comment: File.upload(file).then(function (savedFile) {
            console.log(savedFile);
            $scope.obj.image = savedFile;
            $scope.isImageOneUploading = false;
            $scope.$apply();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to convert Base64 image string to image/file object.

```js
function dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
    var arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
    bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new File([u8arr], filename, {type:mime});
}

//Usage example:
var base64String = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
var file = dataURLtoFile(base64String, 'filename.png');
console.log(file);
```

Comment: I tried this and getting angular.js:15567 TypeError: File is not a constructor

do i need to add any javascript for this?

Comment: @MrJShaun nope. It should work as long as you put it in a `.js` file. Where did you put the function btw?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback , Im putting in a .js file. 

which contains a controller :

angular.module('app')
  .controller('PlaceCtrl',
    function ($scope,....) {
to get the new croped image data.
    $scope.imgSrc = $scope.cropperCrop.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL();
     Inserted your function here, and it says File is not a constructor error

Comment: @MrJShaun here's what you should try. Place the function I've posted outside any controllers/directives/etc. Just put it maybe at the bottom of whatever javascript file you're using. Then call it the way I did. I edited my answer to show you a real working example. Try to run the code snippet and you will see that it indeed outputs an image object.

Comment: And is `Blob` constructor available? You probably don't need `File` anyway, which is indeed not supported by all legacy browsers.

Comment: @JkAlombro this worked! Thanks so much!! added the code outside the controller and it went through correctly to the mongo db. Thanks you so much! been stuck on this for 4 days now