# How to convert DataUrl back into png image file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, todataurl

I have my original image as `png file` as follows:

```
<img src="originalimage.png" >
```

Once I modify the original image using a third party annotation library, for example a simple pencil drawing on the original image, it gives me back a `dataurl` that replaces my `src` with the modified picture. Like so:

```
 <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo...>"
```

Everything works fine, I can view the modified image. However I want to convert the given dataurl back into a `png file` like the one above. Like so:

```
  <img src="modifiedImage.png">
```

How can I convert this `dataurl` in `Javascript` without using any online converters back into my `png file` with the modification applied ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert base64 to image in javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227078/convert-base64-to-image-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: If your trying to override the old file, you can't. You can download a new file (which you can save over the original file).

Comment: What do you mean with "convert it back to png"? You're showing turning an actual file (in data-uri encoding) into that file's _filename_, and I can't think of a single reason why you'd ever do this. So: can you explain why you think you need to do this? Or what you're doing that you think requires you to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can split your image src attribute with (,) comma and (;) semicolumn to get the base encoded string.

And then write it  to the filesystem.

file_put_contents "../somedir/test.png" , base64_decode($baseEncodedString));