# How to return json response and Storage data together in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to return query data and storage Images from laravel controller. My code looks like following :

```
class ClaimController extends Controller{
.....
  public function show(Claim $claim)
  {
    $front_image = Storage::disk('do_spaces')->get($claim->images->front_image);  //image file
    $back_image = Storage::disk('do_spaces')->get($claim->images->back_image);    //image

   // return $front_image   [works]         

    $claim = Claim::all();
   

   //this throws error
   return response()->json([
      'claim' => $claim,
      'images' => [$front_image, $back_image]
   ]);
  }
}
```

Now I far I understand `return->response()->json([])` doesn't send image file. How I can return all data together to frontend app ?

Answer (score 2):

you have the option to return the images from original server which they are stored in or you can return an encoded version of the image as string and in front end reconstruct it.

```
$path = 'myfolder/myimage.png';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

And then use it in front like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VmGLF/1/) :

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...';
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227078/convert-base64-to-image-in-javascript-jquery) is the link for second part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Storage::url()`

```
 $st=\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('do_spaces')->url($claim->images->front_image);

    dd(url($st));
```

`Storage::url()` return `image path` and then `url()` will return full url path

"http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/imagefolder/filename"

Make sure to symbolic link to storage folder by running following command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Also you can do the following without storage url

```
asset('storage/'.$claim->images->front_image)
```

Comment: The image is actually retrieving from Digital ocean remote storage and I have to send it from controller to front end app

Comment: then what  $claim->images->front_image returns

Comment: try to specifiy base url in  'url' => '',  in filesystem for digital ocean then you can return torage::disk('do_spaces')->url