# How to hide an HTML generated link that should only be called by javascript addeventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, django, addeventlistener

I have a Django app, and want to have an image appear on a webpage only when someone clicks a specific element/image 30 times as such:

```
var count = 0;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.querySelector("#PDDO").onclick = function(){
        if(count > 30){
        document.querySelector("#PDDO").src = document.querySelector("#PDDO").dataset.over
        }else{
            count++;
        }
}})
```

When this code is executed, the original image is replaced with the hidden image, which is hardcoded in the URL as such:

```
<img src="{% static 'database/images/original_image.png' %}" width="200", height="200", class="revolve" id="PDDO" data-over="{% static 'database/images/new_image.png' %}">
</div>
```

However, people can easily find the source of this image simply by inspecting the page source code, and I can't seem to hide it:

```
#Page source:
<img src="/static/database/images/original_image.png" ,="" class="revolve" id="PDDO" data-over="/static/database/images/new_image.png" width="200" height="200">
```

I tried to implement js solutions such as below, but to no avail.

```
$("a[data-label='document.querySelector("#PDDO").dataset.over']").hide()
```

What is the best way to hide the image url from the page source?

Comment: If you're talking about "page source" as in **left-click + Inspect** then there isn't a way of hiding it. That's all client side stuff and if isn't in the source than it won't show on the browser

Comment: Then this means that the image should be brought forth only by .js I suppose?

Comment: You might be able to do a `MIMEImage` type thing, and use js like in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227078/convert-base64-to-image-in-javascript-jquery