# Convert base64 object to Image

Tags: javascript, base64

```
  I am using a third party api to generate image from text.It is giving one object with base64. 
  How can i display that in my webpage with img tag. I tried showing that string but that is not working.
```

[image]

Is there any way i can convert that object to actual base64 string ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert base64 to image in javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227078/convert-base64-to-image-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put this base64 value to the src attribute of the img tag.  tag will automatically render base64 to image.
e.g

Comment: Tried. That is not working