# How to Return an Image with Description in FastAPI

Tags: python, file, fastapi

I'm working on a FastAPI project and I need to return an image along with its description to the user. I have implemented the functionality to return the image, but I'm not sure how to include the description.

Here's the code snippet I have for returning the image:

```
@router.post("/generate-post")
async def post(
    post_input: PostInput,
    user_id: Annotated[APIKeyHeader, Depends(get_api_key_and_fetch_user_id)],
):
    response = await generate_post_for_user(post_input.dict(), user_id)
    image_bytes=response["image"]
    return Response(content=image_bytes, media_type="image/png")
```

Now, my question is: how can I send a text description along with the image, for example, "`Image of Patrick`"?

I would appreciate any guidance or examples on how to achieve this in FastAPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode the file content with base64. And you decode it in client side to show file. You can follow this for client side. [convert base64 to image in javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227078/convert-base64-to-image-in-javascript-jquery)

```
import base64


@router.post("/generate-post")
async def post(
    post_input: PostInput,
    user_id: Annotated[APIKeyHeader, Depends(get_api_key_and_fetch_user_id)]):
    
    response = await generate_post_for_user(post_input.dict(), user_id)
    encoded_content = base64.b64encode(response['image'])
    return {"image_content": encoded_content, "image_desc": "Image of Patrick"}
```

Comment: It's the only way that I can Handel it ?

Comment: If you return a response with setting content-type to image, then body must be full of image data. I don't suggest but you can set response header. This's not the best, but works.