# Load image from a url and convert it to a base64string

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to load an image from a url and convert it to a base64 string.

All i get is a string but when I use it as the html source of the image, the images is always blank.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function getBase64Image(imgUrl) {
            var image = new Image();
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            image.src = imgUrl;
            context.drawImage(image,0,0);
            return canvas.toDataURL();
        }
```

The function returns the string.

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't yet tried your code. But it might be as simple as inserting the canvas to the DOM first. Since it is detached from the DOM it might not load the image.

Comment: FYI: You'll need to wait for the image to be loaded. Here is how I works: http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/YvQ5y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to do that:

```
$image = file_get_content($url);
$result = "data:image/png;base64,". base64_encode($image);
```

Comment: The OP wants an answer in Javascript.

Comment: Oh yeah. I didn't noticed it :) 
Nice explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript
And here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644035/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-in-javascript

Comment: I use phonegap, maybe I can use the phoneGap file plugin?

Comment: Here you go: https://gist.github.com/pamelafox/2173589