# How to make POST request with a binary body in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm, http-post

I'm hoping to find a solution for a frustrating problem in Meteor.js. I want to make some API calls to an open API service for face detection. I just need to send an image and receive a JSON object. I cannot find a way to send an image in the post body with meteor.js. The default http package in Meteor has the following method

`HTTP.post(url, [callOptions], [asyncCallback])`

or

```
HTTP.call(method, url, [options], [asyncCallback])
```

with the options

```
[options]  
 data Object
    JSON-able object to stringify and use as the HTTP request body. Overwrites content.
```

My question is how to attach a binary stream to the post body.

any help?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried simply writing the binary to a field in data?  I haven't used the `HTTP` package, but I'd have to think it works the same as all posts.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this with Meteor HTTP.call

if you look at their source code
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/http/httpcall_client.js
You will find this

```
content = JSON.stringify(options.data);
```

To send binary data, you have to use XMLHttpRequest and FileReader API

I wrote an answer to a related topic at [Meteor: uploading file from client to Mongo collection vs file system vs GridFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934141/meteor-uploading-file-from-client-to-mongo-collection-vs-file-system-vs-gridfs) (using Option 2)