# How to handle images in meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, amazon-s3, gridfs, cloudinary

I'm looking for advice how to handle images in meteor. After some research, I noticed that developers usually prefer to use third party API to deal with images such as cloudinary or Amazon S3 but why? What are the pros and cons of using third party API?  Isn't it better to save images locally using techniques that were described here: [Meteor: uploading file from client to Mongo collection vs file system vs GridFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934141/meteor-uploading-file-from-client-to-mongo-collection-vs-file-system-vs-gridfs) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It mostly boils down to whether or not to store images in Mongo. Generally, it's not a good idea, though sometimes I do it for quick prototyping, because it's so easy.

Here are the arguments against it:

https://forums.meteor.com/t/any-reason-not-to-store-images-in-mongo/11021

Answer (score 1):

Why Cloudinary?

Cloudinary provides an end-to-end solution and wraps up all of your image needs in one simple and practical solution. From uploading, to string and managing your media assets and to manipulating and delivering your images via world-wide CDN.

While Meteor is not yet officially integrated to Cloudinary, a [great library has been contributed](https://atmospherejs.com/lepozepo/cloudinary) by a community member and well serves a lot of Cloudinary's users around the world.
Cloudinary introduces a RESTful API to support every developing environment and to allow integrating to every programming language. All of our SDKs are open-source and therefore can be inspected and imitated as required.

For more information: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/

If you have any further questions, please don't hesitate to ask :)